# How to count how many times value1 appears with value2 within keys of an array?

Tags: arrays, count, key, key-value

I can't find an answer for this no matter how much I search. Maybe I'm just asking it wrong, but I hope someone here has an answer for me.

I know how to count values in an array, but I need to count how often a certain value appears with a certain other value within the keys of an array.

I've tried iterating with 'foreach' and 'if' statements, but just can't get it to work.

The array I'm working with looks something like this, simplified to show only the keys I'm interested in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [class] => 2
            [startissue] => 337
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [class] => 11
            [startissue] => 342
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [class] => 11
            [startissue] => 337
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [class] => 2
            [startissue] => 337
        )

)
```

I want to know how many times 'class' 2 appears with 'startissue' 337 (twice in this example), and retain the key/value info. A result array would be great, like so:
Array

```
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [337] => 2
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [337] => 1
            [342] => 1
        )

)
```

I've been able to produce such an array, but I can't get the counts correct, no matter what I try.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a HashMap (or dictionary) that keeps as keys the value of the **class** and as values other dictionaries that have as keys the number of the **startissue** and as values the number of occurences of such assocassiations.

In Java that would look something like `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>`, where the first two integer type are associated (in order) to **class** and **startissue**.

The algorithm would be described like this: you iterate through the elements of the array, and for each class number you map it to a dictionary that will contain a pair of the **startissue** number and 1 (1 occurence). If the class already existed, you just look up the associated dictionary. If the startissue key exists, you just increment its associated value.

EDIT:
Python code (similar to pseudocode):

```
dictionary = {}
for value in initialArray:
    if value["class"] not in dictionary:
        dictionary[value["class"]] = {}

    if value["startissue"] not in dictionary[value["class"]]:
        dictionary[value["class"]][value["startissue"]] = 1
    else:
        dictionary[value["class"]][value["startissue"]] += 1
```

And you would check it like this:

```
if classValue in dictionary and startIssue in dictionary[classValue]:
    return dictionary[classValue][startIssue]
```

Comment: I'd prefer to do this all in PHP, if possible. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like the logic you're describing would just count how may classes are the same and how many startissues are the same. I want to count how many class/startissue pairs are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it. Thanks to @Halex for getting me thinking on the right track. Here's my code, minus the 'isset' and 'in_array' checks (to avoid notices), to make it easier to see:

```
$class=0;
$start=0;
$combo=array();

foreach ($giftlist as $giftlists) {

    $class = $giftlists['class'];
    $start = $giftlists['startissue'];

    if ($giftlists['class']==$class && $giftlists['startissue']==$start) {
        $combo[$class][$start]=$combo[$class][$start]+1;

    } elseif (in_array($class,$giftlists)) {
        $combo[$class][$start]=1;

    } else {
        $combo[$class][$start]=0;
    }

}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($combo); echo '</pre>';
```

Here is the 'if' statement with the checks:

```
if ((in_array($class,$giftlists) && $giftlists['class']==$class) && (in_array($start,$giftlists) && $giftlists['startissue']==$start) && isset($combo[$class]) && isset($combo[$class][$start]) ) {
```

Comment: I'm glad you managed to do it. I updated my answer to include a sample code in a more readable manner (python similar to pseudocode). Since other people may come upon this question from another programming language, I suggest you mark my answer as the solution in order to help them find it quicker. Have a good day!